# Add/Remove elements using JavaScript (add/remove fields with numbered ids and names)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with select elements, and I would like to add and remove by choice some of these elements. This is the html code (also have jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/txhajy2w/):

```
<form id="Form" action="#" method="POST">
    <div id="FormContainer">
        <div class="Row" id="container_0">
            <a id="delete_link_0">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
            </a>
            <select class="type_name" name="type_name_0" id="type_name_0">
                <option value="">Select an Option</option>
                <optgroup label="All Options">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <a id="new_link_0">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

What I would need is:

- clicking on the plus sign would generate a new row (including a div, select and the plus/minus links). However I would need for the new row, new ids and names for the elements (using numbers, for example type_name_1, type_name_2 and so on, changing only the index number).
- clicking on the minus sign, would delete that specific line, and re-number all id's of the remaining elements.

Comment: _new row_ of what? `select`?

Comment: were is your javascript part?

Comment: I am kind of new in JavaScript, that's why I would need help to build the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok to add `select` element again with new ID and to delete the last added select element you can do as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/txhajy2w/1/)**

```
$('#new_link_0').on('click',function(){
    var select=$('.wrap').find('select:last').clone();
    var id=$(select).attr('id').split('_')[2];
    $(select).attr('id','type_name_'+parseInt(id+1));
    $(select).attr('name','type_name_'+parseInt(id+1));
    $(select).insertAfter('.wrap select:last');
});

$('#delete_link_0').on('click',function(){
    $('.wrap').find('select:last').remove();
});
```

**UPDATE**

To add a new Item everytime and reset the whole set of `ids` to proper count you can do as below but you need to follow the below `html` structure:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/txhajy2w/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<form id="Form" action="#" method="POST">
    <div id="FormContainer">            
        <div class="Row" id="container_0">
            <div class="wrap">
               <div class="element"> //wrap each cloning element inside a div
                   <a id="delete_link_0" href="#" class="minus">
                       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
                   </a>
                   <select class="type_name" name="type_name_0" id="type_name_0">
                        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
                        <optgroup label="All Options">
                            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                    <a id="new_link_0" href="#"  class="plus">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click','.plus',function(){
    var element=$('.wrap').find('.element:last').clone();//clone last element always
    var id=parseInt($(element).find('select').attr('id').split('_')[2])+1;
    $(element).find('select').attr('id','type_name_'+id);
    $(element).find('.plus').attr('id','new_link_'+id);
    $(element).find('.minus').attr('id','delete_link_'+id);
    $(element).find('select').attr('name','type_name_'+id);
    $(element).insertAfter('.wrap .element:last'); //insert at the end once modification to the cloned elements has been done
});

$(document).on('click','.minus',function(){
    if($('.wrap .element').length===1) //check for the length if there is only one element then prevent it from deleting
    {
        alert('Cannot delete this! Atleast one item must be there');
        return false;
    }
    $(this).parents('.element').remove();
    $.each($('.element'),function(index,value){//find each .element and reset the `ids` of the controls inside it
        $(this).find('.minus').attr('id','delete_link_'+index);
        $(this).find('.plus').attr('id','new_link_'+index);
        $(this).find('select').attr('id','type_name_'+index).attr('name','type_name_'+index);
    });
});
```

> **Note: Resetting the `ids` might create problem in realtime if you have such operations carried out in you flow**

Comment: Thank you! This would work, however I was not clear on my question, as the plus sign would add a new row right after the clicked row, not at the end. Also, I added a new input after the select item, and added a class and made a split function (that splits text between inputs). Any idea why it does not work with the newly created rows?